# Create Image using Matplotlib imshow meshgrid and custom colors

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to create an image where the x axis is the width, and y axis is the height of the image. And where each point can be given a color based on a RBG mapping. From looking at imshow() from Matplotlib I guess I need to create a meshgrid on the form (NxMx3) where 3 is a tuple or something similar with the rbg colors.

But so far I have not managed to understand how to do that. Lets say I have this example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

x_min = 1 
x_max = 5
y_min = 1 
y_max = 5
Nx = 5 #number of steps for x axis
Ny = 5 #number of steps for y axis

x = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, Nx)
y = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, Ny)

#Can then create a meshgrid using this to get the x and y axis system
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

#imagine I have some funcion that does someting based on the x and y values
def somefunc(x_value, y_value):
    #do something and return rbg based on that
    return x_value + y_value

res = somefunc(xx, yy)

cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap', ['white', 'blue', 'black'])
plt.figure(dpi=100)
plt.imshow(res, cmap=cmap, interpolation='bilinear')

plt.show()
```

And this creates a plot, but what would I have to do if my goal was to give spesific rbg values based on x and y values inside somefunc and make the resulting numpy array into a N x M x 3 array

I tried to make the somefunc function return a tuple of rbg values to use (r, b g) but that does not seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will of course completely depend on what you want to do with the values you supply to the function. So let's assume you just want to put the x values as the red channel and the y values as the blue channel, this could look like

```
def somefunc(x_value, y_value):
    return np.dstack((x_value/5., np.zeros_like(x_value), y_value/5.))
```

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_min = 1 
x_max = 5
y_min = 1 
y_max = 5
Nx = 5 #number of steps for x axis
Ny = 5 #number of steps for y axis

x = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, Nx)
y = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, Ny)

#Can then create a meshgrid using this to get the x and y axis system
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

#imagine I have some funcion that does someting based on the x and y values
def somefunc(x_value, y_value):
    return np.dstack((x_value/5., np.zeros_like(x_value), y_value/5.))


res = somefunc(xx, yy)

plt.figure(dpi=100)
plt.imshow(res)

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you already have a (more complicated) function that returns an RGB tuple you may loop over the grid to fill an empty array with the values of the function.

```
#If you already have some function that returns an RGB tuple
def somefunc(x_value, y_value):
    if x_value > 2 and y_value < 3:
        return np.array(((y_value+1)/4., (y_value+2)/5., 0.43))
    elif x_value <=2:
        return np.array((y_value/5., (x_value+3)/5., 0.0))
    else:
        return np.array((x_value/5., (y_value+5)/10., 0.89))
# you may loop over the grid to fill a new array with those values
res = np.zeros((xx.shape[0],xx.shape[1],3))
for i in range(xx.shape[0]):
    for j in range(xx.shape[1]):
        res[i,j,:] = somefunc(xx[i,j],yy[i,j])



plt.figure(dpi=100)
plt.imshow(res)
```

[image]

Comment: I am having some problems understanding the dstack function here. And also are there some rules for what can be put back into the array? If I for instance did calculate something else instead of the np.zeros_like(x_value) Say for instance the number 0.4 then I get "ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly" Are there some rules about everything having to be some type of numpy value?

Comment: The returned array needs to be of shape (n,m,3) or (n,m,4), in your case n=Ny, m=Nx. You are totally free on how you create this array. In the solution here I just stacked 3 (n,m) arrays on top of each other to get a (n,m,3) shaped array out.

Comment: Ok, im not quite sure I am getting it. Lets say that the somefunc is modified a bit and instead says that if x + y is larger than 5 then one color, and if not another one. How would you construct that array. And how would that change if for instance the somefunc function would have some form of for i in range(xx) in it. Could I still use np.vectorize and then run it over the meshgrid?

Comment: For the case "if x + y is larger than 5.." you wouldn't create an image at all. Instead you'd just plot that binary array with a colormap, `plt.imshow(xx+yy>5 , cmap=matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(["blue", "pink"]))`. `for i in range(xx)` does not make sense, so I'm not sure what that should give, but you may sure define some function an use `vectorize` to apply it to each element of an array.

Comment: Im not sure if I should edit my first post or something else to show an example of the kind of function I am thinking about. So I shared a example of the code here instead https://codeshare.io/GkrgJA Why would that function not work even after I vectorize it?

Comment: You cannot `return` inside a loop, because that will just return the value of the first loop step.

Comment: But in this case I want to break the loop and return the current values when the condition there is meet. Do you have any other tips for how to make it work, and should the way of creating the resulting array work as it is except for the return inside the loop?

Comment: I updated the answer with another example if that helps.